# Setup webpack on my basic JS project NO framework

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I'm trying to setup webpack on my JS project, but it always flashing errors

```
> code@1.0.0 build
> webpack

'Workflows\Code\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\KalBonyanAlmarsos\04 - JavaScript\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)     
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.2.0
```

File Structure & Webpack Config file

screenshot

[image: 1]

Did you face this before?